# Persisting One to many Doctrine Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am using doctrine MongoDb in my project. I have two documents: Question and QuizzPart.

QuizzPart references many questions, for this I did the following declaration:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Question", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $questions = array();
```

and the question references one QuizzPart.

```
/**
*@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="QuizzPart", inversedBy="questions") 
*/
protected $quizzPart ;
```

But in my crud  (Sonata admin Bundle) when I create (or edit) a Quiz Part and try to add in it some questions. There is no reference to the QuizzPart in my Question document in the database (But the quizzPart references many questions). I didn't know the origin of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research I found the solution, in fact the problem was in the sonata admin bundle (the quizzPartAdmin Class) and not  in the declaration of the models:
it is about setting the flag 'by_reference' to  false :

```
        $formMapper
        ->add('questions', 'sonata_type_collection', array('label' => 'add a question', 'by_reference' => false)
        , array(
        'edit'     => 'inline',
        'inline'   => 'table',
        'sortable' => 'id',
        )) 
      ;
```